# Rate limit outgoing PHP+curl requests

Tags: php, api, curl, limit

Is there a way to rate limit (with delay) outgoing PHP+curl requests to an external server, so that there are only n requests per second? PHP is used in Fastcgi mode so not possible to use sleep.

Comment: How is the PHP script executed? Per browser or cron/schedule?

Comment: Per browser, there are multiple PHP Fastcgi processes. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be global rate limit for nginx.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. There's the curl multi handler...

(You can do it in a OOP fashion way using [this library](https://gist.github.com/3459690))

For instance:

```
    // Creates the curl multi handle
    $mh = curl_multi_init();
    $handles = array();

    foreach($urls as $url)
    {
        // Create a new single curl handle
        $ch = curl_init();

        // Set options
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 300);

        // Add to the multi handle
        curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch);

        // Put the handles in an array to loop this later on
        $handles[] = $ch;
    }

    // Execute the multi handle
    $running=null;

    do
    {
        $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh,$running);

        // Added a usleep for 0.50 seconds to reduce load
        usleep (250000);
    }
    while($running > 0);

    // Get the content of the urls (if there is any)
    $output = array();
    for($i=0; $i<count($handles); $i++)
    {
        // Get the content of the handle
        $content = curl_multi_getcontent($handles[$i]);
        $output[] = $content;

        if($printOutput) {
            echo $content;
        }

        // Remove the handle from the multi handle
        curl_multi_remove_handle($mh,$handles[$i]);
    }

    // close the multi curl handle to free system resources
    curl_multi_close($mh);
```

Comment: This won't work since PHP is in Fastcgi mode, so there are multiple PHP processes. Not sure if the above can prevent multiple outgoing connections from PHP processes.

Comment: @vamur Try out the linked gist.

Comment: @vimur linked gist is no longer there.

Answer (score 2):

You can control the rate with the [token bucket algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token_bucket). As you want to control the rate of all your PHP processes for one resource you will need to share the state of the bucket. You can do this in a threadsafe way with my implementation: [bandwidth-throttle/token-bucket](https://github.com/bandwidth-throttle/token-bucket)

```
use bandwidthThrottle\tokenBucket\Rate;
use bandwidthThrottle\tokenBucket\TokenBucket;
use bandwidthThrottle\tokenBucket\BlockingConsumer;
use bandwidthThrottle\tokenBucket\storage\FileStorage;

$storage  = new FileStorage(__DIR__ . "/api.bucket");
$rate     = new Rate(10, Rate::SECOND);
$bucket   = new TokenBucket(10, $rate, $storage);
$consumer = new BlockingConsumer($bucket);
$bucket->bootstrap(10);

// This blocks all processes to the rate of 10 requests/second
$consumer->consume(1);

$api->doSomething();
```

Comment: Laravel as of 5.2 has now added a middleware to limit calls per N minutes. This though covers my issue of the bucket size allocation per month. Nice library.